# PyQt5 - How can I delete the default empty field placed around a Tab widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tabs, pyqt5

I'm writing a GUI with PyQt5 and I realized that the Tab widgets have a default empty field placed around them (see the attached screenshot). How can I delete it?

[image]

Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 tabs'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:red")

        self.show()
    
class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300,200)

        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab 2")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is the output of `print(app.style().metaObject().className())`

Comment: try add `self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` and/or `self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` after `self.setLayout(self.layout)` inside MyTableWidget.

Comment: @eyllanesc the print output is `QWindowsVistaStyle` and unfortunately the two instructions don't delete the "extra border".

Comment: try add `app.setStyle("fusion")` :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah, if I change the style, the "extra border" doesn't exist, so in this way the issue is solved, but I don't want to use "fusion" for the style, I want the default one.

Comment: @TurboC you can set the style only to a single widget, *after* creating its children, using `self.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`. If you want to keep the default look for the tab bar you can use a QTabBar linked with a QStackedWidget (which is exactly what QTabWidget is, it only provides helper functions to allow direct management of both). Otherwise, you could create a QProxyStyle and reimplement the `drawPrimitive` for the `PE_FrameTabWidget` element.

Comment: @musicamante ciao musicamante, your last solution sounds good, but I don't have enough experience with PyQt to implement it. can you show me the instructions in order to change the style of the Tab widget in my code please? I just want to remove the "extra border".

Comment: @TurboC unfortunately, since I don't use Windows, I cannot offer you a code valid enough to achieve what you want, I'd need to understand how the style actually behaves and then see how can it be fixed.